# Gemfire Partitioning : Transaction Issues

Tags: gemfire

In GemFire documentation and forums we normally see the use case of Customer, Order, Order items and partitioning done on these regions with Order and Order items co-located with Customer.

Our use case has a Capacity region which holds huge data and holds the Inventory info and needs to be partitioned. It holds the details of each train capacity.
When we do a booking suppose a person is going from point A to B, he might choose a route such as A - C - B
Where A-C he goes by train1 and C-B he goes by train2

So when booking is done from the inventory - for train1 and train2 the capacity must be updated(reduced in this case).

Considering Capacity as a partitioned region, train1 entry and train2 entry can be on seperate data nodes. Here we cannot do any kind of  data co-location on the train info.

How can we update the train1 and train2 data in a single transaction without getting TransactionDataNotColocated exception?

Is this possible or is it not possible to Partition Capacity region?

Pivotal site mentions case studies of Indian Rail, China rail so such use case might be a very common one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered something like this with an airline inventory system.  The short answer is that you won't be able to use transactions to span the whole purchase since there is no partitioning scheme that colocates trains that are part of any possible journey.

You have to get creative.  I've outlined one solution below.  It may or may not exactly meet your needs but it should at least give you the idea of how to build a solution out of the pieces GemFire provides.

One way of doing this is to use the idea of "reserved seats".  A "reserved seat" is one that *may* have been sold - its "in doubt". Let a "journey" be one train going from location A to B on a particular date. This will be very large and will be stored in a partition region.  Each train-journey would carry on it a capacity , seats sold and a list of reservations.  Each reservation contains the timestamp the reservation was made, and unique purchase identifier.

At any given time, the available capacity on a train-journey is initial capacity - seats sold - reservations.size()

When selling a trip, which may contain multiple journeys

`for each leg of the journey 
start txn
   retrieve train-journey
   check available capacity (see formula above)
   if capacity > 0 add a reservation to the list
commit`

If you succeed in reserving capacity on every journey, complete the sale and record the unique purchase identifier in a "recent purchase" region, along with a list of keys of all journeys in the trip. If any journey on the trip doesn't have capacity you tell the user the trip is not available.

This algorithm never oversells but can leave reservations in place that do not correspond to a completed purchase.  This could happen because a journey on the trip was unavailable or because of failure.

The last piece of the puzzle is a couple of background jobs to process reservations and turn them into seats sold.  One job would simply pass through all of the train-journeys on a regular basis and remove expired reservations from the list.  Note that this can be done in an entirely distributed fashion with no intra-node coordination.

The other job would deal with recent purchases.  You would loop over the recent purchases region.  For each recent purchase, run an onRegion Function against the journey region with a filter consisting of the list of journey keys.  This Function would , in a transaction, find the journey (local key lookup) , remove the corresponding reservation and increment seats sold.  Note that this Function is idempotent and does not require global transactions.  If there is a failure, it can just be run again.

Hope this helps.